# FFMPEG extract 1 frame from video, consecutive frames from other video and overlay the latter on the former with one command

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two videos, A and B. I want to:

- Extract **one** frame from A at a certain time point, which will be used as a "background"
- Extract **a number of consecutive frames** from B, starting from that same time point
- Rescale and overlay each frame of B on top of the "background" (frame of A)

So for example I want to extract one still image from A, and overlay on top of it 20 consecutive frames from B, one at a time, resulting in 20 images which will all have the same still background (the frame from A) but each with a different overlay (one consecutive frame from B at a time).

I can do this with the following two commands:

```
ffmpeg -ss 730.250 -i A.mkv -frames:v 1 still.jpg

ffmpeg -y
  -i still.jpg
  -ss 730.250 -i B.mkv -frames:v 20
  -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=iw/3:-1[tmp],[0:v][tmp]overlay[out]"
  -map [out] out%d.jpg
```

However I'd like to know if it's possible

1. To combine the above commands into one working ffmpeg command (not two commands with the `&&` operator)
2. Not to save `still.jpg` on disk but feed the extracted frame directly to the filters

I've tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -y
  -ss 730.250 -i A.mkv -frames:v 1 -f null -
  -ss 730.250 -i B.mkv -frames:v 20
  -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=iw/3:-1[tmp],[0:v][tmp]overlay[out]"
  -map [out] out%d.jpg
```

Which works but not in the way I want it to. The frame of A is not saved on disk but the resulting 20 images are not correct; the overlays are as expected, but the "background" behaves the same way as the overlays (each background consists of one consecutive frame of A, one at a time instead of being one still frame at the specified time point).

How do I achieve the same results as with the first two commands?

Comment: You may now the `-filter_complex_script` option. [Here's](https://johnnn.tech/q/ffmpeg-filter_complex_script-crop-blurbox-with-time-based-values/) an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the trim filters to only use the desired duration from each input.

`ffmpeg -y -ss 730.250 -i A.mkv -ss 730.250 -i B.mkv -filter_complex "[1:v]trim=end_frame=20,scale=iw/3:-1,settb=1/25,setpts=N/25/TB[tmp];[0:v]trim=end_frame=1,settb=1/25,setpts=0[base];[base][tmp]overlay[out]" -map [out] -vsync 0 -enc_time_base 1/25 out%d.jpg`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work though: the command runs and I get `Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)`

Comment: It works now after your edit. I had to replace all instances of "25" with "23.976" which is the fps of both my videos, otherwise I was getting an error `Invalid pts (12) <= last (12). Video encoding failed` and the output images were only 13 instead of 20. I also tried your command without the `settb` and `setpts` filters but I got the same error and only one (the first) output image. Can you please explain why we need to set the pts and the timebase when using this method? Also the addition of `-vsync 0` doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Timestamps are manually set with a fine-enough timebase to ensure sync during overlay. For video output, this is not required, but with images you can get duplicates. Added another option to avoid having to change the TB rate.